# Mercurial: Most recent change per file

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking for a way to make Mercurial output a table like this:

```
File        Most recent revision changing the file          Date of that revision
====        ======================================          =====================
foo.py      44159adb0312                                    2018-09-16 12:24
...         ...                                             ...
```

This is just like github does it on the "Code" overview page. (screenshot from torvalds/linux):
[image: screenshot github]

"Most recent" could refer the date or to the DAG hierarchy relative to the current changeset, or maybe to the current branch. Perhaps the latter is more useful, but in my particular use case, it doesn't make a difference.

I'd also like to be able to provide a list of files or a subdirectory for which I want the table. (I don't necessarily want it for everything)

I am aware that I could do it using a small script, looping over `hg log -l 1 <file>`, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient / more natural solution.

Comment: I don't think what Github is showing is precisely the "latest" change to each file; I think instead it is showing the last change to the file on whatever branch is currently displayed. Would you want to see the truly latest changes for each file, even if they were on different branches?

Comment: @DaveInCaz, good point. I adjusted my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get around looping over all files. Yet with `hg manifest` you get that list of files. Then template the output as needed:

```
for f in $(hg ma); do hg log -l1 $f -T"$f\t\t{rev}:{node|short}\t\t{date|isodate}"; done
```

This gives output like

```
.hgignore               38289:f9c426385853              2018-06-09 13:34 +0900
.hgsigs         38289:f9c426385853              2018-06-09 13:34 +0900
.hgtags         38289:f9c426385853              2018-06-09 13:34 +0900
```

You might want to twiddle more with the output formatting. See the [mercurial wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/templates) for a complete overview of output templating.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Somehow more efficient / more natural solution can be:</strike>

- create template|style for desired log output (I can't predict, which way will be better *for you*)
- create alias for `hg log -l 1 --template ...` or `hg log -l 1 --style ...`

**EDIT**

A lot later, more correct solution (from [recent discoveries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075258/960558)) with `hg grep`

```
hg grep "." "set:**.py" --files-with-matches -d -q -T"{files % '{file} {date|age}\n'}"
```

Part of output in test-repo

```
hggit/__init__.py 7 weeks ago
hggit/git_handler.py 7 weeks ago
hggit/gitdirstate.py 7 weeks ago
…
```

You have to modify fileset in order to get results only for part of your tree (for *all branches*) and, maybe, template in order to fulfill your needs.

I didn't have fileset for selecting "files in branch X" just now, I think, it will be something using `revs()` predicate

> "revs(revs, pattern)"
>
> Evaluate set in the specified revisions. If the
> revset match multiple revs, this will return file matching pattern in
> any of the revision.

because *some not published predicates* (according to examples, see @ "set:revs('wdir()'..." for referencing working directory) can be used for defining revset and I can't discover/predict the correct form for branch predicate

Comment: AFAIU, a single `hg log -l 1` command would not do what I want. For example, if there are files `foo1.py` and `foo2.py` and they have been changed most recently in *different* changesets, I want *two* changesets to be displayed: one for `foo1.py` and one for `foo2.py`.

Comment: @srs - OK, add (in Mercurial) shell-alias with `ls | xargs` in it

Answer (score 0):

Git will follow the commit DAG, because that's all it has.  In Mercurial, you have (many) more options because you have more data.

Probably the ideal option here is `follow(file, .)` (combined with `first` or `last` as appropriate).  But as `hg help revset` will tell you, you have the following options (I've shrunk the list to the obvious applicable ones):

- `ancestors(set[, depth])`

  Use this with the `set` being `.` to get ancestors of the current commit, for instance, if you want to do DAG-following a la Git.  Or, use `::.`, which is basically the same.
- `branch(string or set)`

  Use this with `.` to get all commits in the current branch.  Combine with other restrictors (e.g., `parents`) to avoid looking at later commits in the current branch if you're not at the tip of the current branch.
- `file(pattern)`

  Use this with a glob pattern to find changesets that affect a given file.
- `filelog(pattern)`

  Like `file` but faster, trading off some accuracy for speed (see documentation for further details).
- `follow([file[, startrev]])`

  To quote the documentation:

  > An alias for `"::."` (ancestors of the working directory's first parent).
  >   If file pattern is specified, the histories of files matching given
  >   pattern in the revision given by startrev are followed, including
  >   copies.
- `modifies(pattern)`

  Use this (with any pattern, not just glob) to find changesets that modify some file or directory.  I think this is limited to `M` type modifications, not addition or removal of files, as there is also `adds(pattern)` and `removes(pattern)`.  Use all three, `or`-ed together, to find any add/modify/remove operations.
- `first(set, [n])`
  `last(set, [n])`
  `limit(set[, n[, offset]])`

  Use this to extract a particular entry out of the revset.

When searching forwards (the default), `last(follow(file, .))` seems to work nicely to locate the correct revision.  As you noted, you have to do this once per file—it will definitely go faster if you write your own Mercurial plug-in to do this without reloading the rest of the system all the time.